# Como utilizar un sharePreferences con un tableLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy creando una aplicación que me resta dos fechas y me muestra la cantidad de días, pero el resultado quiero que me lo muestre en otro layout. el sharePrefereneces me podría mostrar dos resultados de manera lineal, pero quiero que me guarde el día, mes, año de inicio y el resultado de los días en una misma linea... No sé si exista otra manera de obtener lo que requiero. Gracias por la ayuda

```
Año1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAñoInicio);
        Mes1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMesInicio);
        Dia1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDiaInicio);
        Año2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAñoFin);
        Mes2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMesFin);
        Dia2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDiaFin);
        resultado = (EditText) findViewById(etTotal3);
        btnGuardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuardarT3);
        Lista = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.ListaT3);

        Calendar C2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        a1 = C2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        m1 = C2.get(Calendar.MONTH) +1;
        d1 = C2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        a2 = C2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        m2 = C2.get(Calendar.MONTH) +1;
        d2 = C2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        Dia1.setText(""+d1);
        Mes1.setText(""+m1);
        Año1.setText(""+a1);
        Dia2.setText(""+d1);
        Mes2.setText(""+m1);
        Año2.setText(""+a1);

        a1 = Integer.valueOf(Año1.getText().toString());
        a2 = Integer.valueOf(Año2.getText().toString());
        m1 = Integer.valueOf(Mes1.getText().toString());
        m2 = Integer.valueOf(Mes2.getText().toString());
        d1 = Integer.valueOf(Dia1.getText().toString());
        d2 = Integer.valueOf(Dia2.getText().toString());

        rA = a2 - a1;
        rM = m2 - m1;
        rD = d2 - d1;

        Rt = (rA*360)+(rM*30)+(rD+1);

        resultado.setText(""+Rt);


        btnGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                a1 = Integer.valueOf(Año1.getText().toString());
                a2 = Integer.valueOf(Año2.getText().toString());
                m1 = Integer.valueOf(Mes1.getText().toString());
                m2 = Integer.valueOf(Mes2.getText().toString());
                d1 = Integer.valueOf(Dia1.getText().toString());
                d2 = Integer.valueOf(Dia2.getText().toString());

                rA = a2 - a1;
                rM = m2 - m1;
                rD = d2 - d1;

                Rt = (rA*360)+(rM*30)+(rD+1);

                resultado.setText(""+Rt);

                String [] cadena={"Inicio: ", Dia1.getText().toString()+ " / ", Mes1.getText().toString()+ " / ",Año1.getText().toString()+ "   Dias: ",resultado.getText().toString()};
                TableLayout tabla=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.ListaT3);
                TextView textView;
                //abrimos el table row agregar las filas
                TableRow row=new TableRow(getBaseContext());
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

                    textView = new TextView(getBaseContext());

                    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

                    textView.setPadding(10, 5, 30, 30);

                    textView.setText(cadena[i]);

                    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

                    row.addView(textView);
                }

                tabla.addView(row);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

//Lo que necesito es que lo que se me muestra acá me lo almacene en la memoria interna y me lo muestre, igual en otro layout.... P.D: no se utilizar bases de datos :(

Comment: no veo SharedPreferences en tu código

Comment: quieres pasar datos entre actividades?

Comment: Hola! Así es... la idea es que cada resultado se muestre en otra actividad, junto con la fecha 1, algo así:       Inicio 01/11/2017 Dias 28 y la siguiente debajo de esta, así susesibamente

Comment: Donde esta tu `SharedPreference`?

Comment: Podrias mostrarnos tu código del `SharedPreferences` donde intentas guardar los datos?

Comment: intenté implementarlo pero no supe como poner todos los datos seguidos, por eso lo quité :(...

Comment: lee un poco más acerca de SharedPreference y lograrás implementarlo :)

Comment: Trata de volver a implementarlo y muestranos para que podamos ayudarte. En cuanto a lo de poner todos los datos seguidos lo que podrías hacer es guardar cada dato en un `String` y luego simplemente concatenarlos en tu `TextView` algo asi `miTextView.setText("Inicio: " + fecha + " Dias: " + nroDias)` donde fecha y nroDias son tus variables guardadas en el teléfono con el SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente crea los métodos para guardar y obtener los valores de la preferencia:

```
public void guardarDato(Context context, String valorKey, String valor) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(valorKey, valor);
    editor.commit();
}

public String obtenerDato(Context context, valorKey) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return  preferences.getString(valorKey, "");
}
```

ahora usando el método `guardarDato()` puedes guardar los valores de día, mes y año en la preferencia:

```
guardarDato(getApplicationContext(), "dia", Dia1.getText().toString());
guardarDato(getApplicationContext(), "mes", Mes1.getText().toString());
guardarDato(getApplicationContext(), "ano", Año1.getText().toString());
```

Ahora como ejemplo para obtener el valor del día, lo obtenemos mediante los "key" que definimos, en este caso "dia", "mes", "ano":

```
String valorDia = obtenerDato(getApplicationContext(), "dia");
String valorMes = obtenerDato(getApplicationContext(), "mes");
String valorAno = obtenerDato(getApplicationContext(), "ano");
```

de esta forma puedes obtener los valores que fueron guardados en la preferencia y usarlos en otra parte de la aplicación.

Comment: Excelente Jorgesys, me fue de mucha utilidad. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Un placer amigo, en el sitio ya puedes encontrar información acerca de SharedPreferences, te aconsejo también revisar las demás preguntas, saludos!